# aapt.exe error on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to add facebook SDK my project on unity, when I added SDK it given error "build-tools/aapt.exe" I've searched this on google and so many people said that delete inside the build-tools folder, so I delete inside build-tools folder but now given error as follow

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Users/Muhammet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Muhammet/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.facebook.android:com.facebook.applinks:com.facebook.common:com.facebook.core:com.facebook.login:com.facebook.messenger:com.facebook.places:com.facebook.share -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-wrapper-7.11.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-applinks\res" -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res" -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-core\res" -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-login\res" -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-messenger\res" -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-places\res" -S "C:\Users\Muhammet\Desktop\unity_Projeler\test3d1\test2d\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-share\res"', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:44)
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:28)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:263)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

What should I do for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
This error can be cause due to many things. 
1) Update JDK
2) Check Java Path.
3) Update Android SDK
4) Delete duplicate .jar file in unity asset folder under plugins folder. 
5) Check target version in AndroidManifest.xml and Player Settings which should be same. 
6) If these doesn’t work. Your error is causing “Android-27”. So go to androidskd > build-tools and remove the folder android-27 folder and build again.
```